# Javascript test to see if first 4 characters are correct

Tags: javascript

I am trying to run a script to see if i can verify the first 4  characters in a text box.  The text box works to tell me that the characters are not there but when i put the first 4 number in correctly it still gives me the same error.  Also the text box has a min of 15 characters and a max of 16 characters.

Here is the script:

```
var check_card_no = function (event){
check_digits = card_no.substring(0, 4);
if(check_digits=="9999"){
return true;
}
else{
    alert("please enter valid Credit Card Number");
    patron_card_no.value="";
    patron_card_no.focus();
    return false;
}
}
```

Just so every can see the full code here is everything for the script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// Caspio form elements  kkw
var Ticket_PriceField = document.getElementById('InsertRecordTicket_Price');
var Number_of_TicketsField = document.getElementById('InsertRecordNumber_of_Tickets');
var totalField = document.querySelectorAll('span[class^="cbParamVirtual4"]')[0];
var patron_card_no = document.getElementById('InsertRecordPatron_Credit_Card_Number');
var card_no=patron_card_no.value;
var card_date=document.getElementById('InsertRecordPatron_Credit_Card_Exp');
var caspioForm = document.getElementById('caspioform');
// Event handler
var calculateTotal = function (event)
{
// TODO: Do something on value change -->
totalField.innerHTML = Ticket_PriceField.value * Number_of_TicketsField.value;
}
// Run total calculation on input
Number_of_TicketsField.addEventListener('input', calculateTotal);


// credit card no check
var check_card_no = function (event){

check_digits = card_no.substring(0, 4);
if(check_digits=="9999" ){
return true;
}
else{
    alert("please enter valid Credit Card Number");
    patron_card_no.value="";
    patron_card_no.focus();
    return false;
}
}
patron_card_no.addEventListener('change', check_card_no);


function check_credit_card_date(){
var credit_card_date=card_date.value;
var card_month=credit_card_date.substring(0, 2);
var card_year=credit_card_date.substring(2, 4);
if(credit_card_date.length==4 && (card_month > 0 && card_month < 13) && (card_year > 16 && card_month < 31) ){
return true;
}
else
{
    alert("please enter valid Credit Card Exp. Date ");
    card_date.value="";
    card_date.focus();
    return false;
}
}
card_date.addEventListener('change', check_credit_card_date);
</script>
```

Comment: You'll have to show what `card_no` is. Have you tried `console.log(card_no)` and verified that it contains the user input?

Comment: I am calling the var  
var patron_card_no =document.getElementById('InsertRecordPatron_Credit_Card_Number');
var card_no=patron_card_no.value;

Comment: Debug your script and view the values of card_no and check_digits, the logic seems fine.

Comment: I have checked it and debugged it.  For some reason the error keeps showing even if i put the 9999 in for the first 4 numbers of the text box.  This is where i am getting confused at.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show how the `check_card_no` function is called. The code that sets the value of `card_no` needs to be inside your event handler.

Comment: @nnnnnn Can you give me an example of what you mean.

Comment: @JJJ I have check to see if it reads the user input and it does.  I have tested this on a demo and on the site and yes it does see the input of the user.

Comment: I mean that you have to move the line that sets `card_no=patron_card_no.value;` inside your `check_card_no` function, so that your validation will use the *current* value of the input field. (At the moment you get the value from the field *once* when the page first loads so you only validate that initial value.)

Comment: @nnnnnn  Thank you for that.  I was able to get the error to now show up when i put in the correct number.  To everyone else that posted on this thank you also.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have some kind of framework providing binding between the view and your javascript, you explicitly have to read again the `<input>` when you change it.

Comment: Are you thinking of code like this:

'patron_card_no.addEventListener('change', check_card_no);'

Comment: Yes (i suppose, since i don't know what the `check_card_no` function does), but if you need a more specific control, you trigger that function manually. For example just before you do the check

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you pass `String` input to your function.

```js
var check_card_no = function (card_no){
check_digits = card_no.substring(0, 4);
if(check_digits=="9999"){
 return true;
}
else{
    //alert("please enter valid Credit Card Number");
    //patron_card_no.value="";
    //patron_card_no.focus();
    return false;
}
}


console.log('Valid Card test= '+check_card_no('99992222'));
console.log('Invalid Card test= '+check_card_no('2288888'));
```

Comment: I need for a error message to appear for me to see if the number is wrong.  I dont believe that console.log will do that.

Am i correct or will it show an error?

Comment: @ericjw316 Open the developer tools and look at the console. The messages get displayed there.

Comment: @ericjw316 I used `console` only to show you do get `false` when you pass wrong card number. How do you want to show the error?

Comment: @Arshad I would like to do that but the software the company is using doesnt allow that.  This is why i have to have an error message.